# Only show button when .active class is not first child

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a multi step form using jQuery and I'm trying to only show the `#prev` button when the active class isn't on the first child. By default I have added `display:none` to `#prev` to hide it on load but I'm struggling to display it when the `.active` class is added onto the other sections.

When targeting this in a if statement using the `is(":not(:first-child))` it works but only shows when the active class is added onto `#step3`.

Can anyone tell me how to ensure the button is only visible when the class `.active` is on every section except `#step1`?

```
if(active.is(":not(:first-child)")) {
    $('#prev').show();
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="multi-step-wrapper" id="multi-step">
            <div id="progressbar">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="steps-inner">
                <div class="multi-step-section active" id="step1"></div>
                <div class="multi-step-section" id="step2"></div>
                <div class="multi-step-section" id="step3"></div>
                <div class="multi-step-section" id="step4"></div>
                <div class="multi-step-section" id="step5"></div>
                <div class="multi-step-section" id="step6"></div>
                <div class="multi-form-actions">
                    <button id="prev" type="button">Back</button>
                    <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#prev {
  display: none;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('.multi-form-actions button').on('click', function() {

  var el = $(this).attr('id');
  var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');

  if(active.is(":not(:first-child)")) {
    $('#prev').show();
  }

  active.removeClass('active');

  if(el == 'prev') {
      active.prev('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
  }
  else if(el = 'next') {
      active.next('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
  }

});
```

Comment: $( ".steps-inner div:first-child" ).hasClass("active"); I think this should work

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with that conditional, and not the following conditional that sets the active class on an element, regardless if it is the first or last element?

Comment: There's also a typo with the last `if` using `=` instead of `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do in order to make this work:

1. Hide all steps that are not active (I assume you're doing this already and left it out for the sake of a shorter example code)
2. <strike>Remove the active state from all the sibling step containers</strike> *actually, that's not necessary and was a fallacy on my side*
3. Update the element held in the collection of  the `active` variable with the next/previous step accordingly
4. move the button status check after that
5. hide the button when the active step is the first one

You'll also have to handle the case when all steps are through, but that's out of the scope of this question.

I also simplified the code to get rid of some redundance.

```js
$('.multi-form-actions button').on('click', function() {
  var el = $(this).attr('id');
  var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');

  // also remove active class from siblings
  active.removeClass('active');

  if(el === 'prev' || el === 'next') { // in case you have any other buttons
    active = active[el]('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');;
  }
  
  // show or hide prev button depending on condition
  $('#prev')[active.is(":not(:first-child)") ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

```css
#prev,
.multi-step-section {
  display: none;
}

.multi-step-section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<div class="multi-step-wrapper" id="multi-step">
  <div id="progressbar">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-inner">
    <div class="multi-step-section active" id="step1">step1</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step2">step2</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step3">step3</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step4">step4</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step5">step5</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step6">step6</div>
    <div class="multi-form-actions">
      <button id="prev" type="button">Back</button>
      <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So a few fixes to your logic.

1. Fixed the typo of `=` on the else if.
2. Set the `active` to the new active once it's adjusted.
3. Check if the active is the first element **after** it has been adjusted, not before, so it is accurate.
4. As a bonus, also added the hiding of the prev if it is changed back to the first element.

```js
$('.multi-form-actions button').on('click', function() {
  var el = $(this).attr('id');
  var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');

  active.removeClass('active');

  if (el == 'prev') {
    active = active.prev('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
  } else if (el == 'next') {
    active = active.next('.multi-step-section').addClass('active');
  }

  if (active.is(":not(:first-child)")) {
    $('#prev').show();
  } else {
    $('#prev').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#prev {
  display: none;
}

.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-step-wrapper" id="multi-step">
  <div id="progressbar">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-inner">
    <div class="multi-step-section active" id="step1">a</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step2">b</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step3">c</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step4">d</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step5">e</div>
    <div class="multi-step-section" id="step6">f</div>
    <div class="multi-form-actions">
      <button id="prev" type="button">Back</button>
      <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this which will also make sure there is a next active step to activate.

```js
$('.multi-form-actions button').on('click', function() {

  var el = $(this).attr('id');
  var active = $('.multi-step-section.active');
  var nextActive; 

  if(el == 'prev') {
    nextActive = active.prev('.multi-step-section');
  }
  else if(el = 'next') {
    nextActive = active.next('.multi-step-section');
  }

  if (nextActive.length > 0) {
    active.removeClass('active');

    if(nextActive.is(":first-child")) {
      $('#prev').hide();
    }
    else {
      $('#prev').show();
    }

    nextActive.addClass('active');  
  }
});
```

```css
#prev {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-step-wrapper" id="multi-step">
    <div id="progressbar">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="steps-inner">
        <div class="multi-step-section active" id="step1"></div>
        <div class="multi-step-section" id="step2"></div>
        <div class="multi-step-section" id="step3"></div>
        <div class="multi-step-section" id="step4"></div>
        <div class="multi-step-section" id="step5"></div>
        <div class="multi-step-section" id="step6"></div>
        <div class="multi-form-actions">
            <button id="prev" type="button">Back</button>
            <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```